# Probability that two of three devices will not work

Tags: probability

There are three devices A, B and C. Each of this device has probability of failure a, b and c respectively where $a, b, c \in (0, 1)$. What is probability that A and B will be broken and C will work ok?

I was thinking about: $P = a \cdot b \cdot (1 - c)$, but I'm not sure.

Comment: There's an assumption you have to make there...

Comment: Assumptions of independence are often not made explicit.  They usually ought to be.

Comment: One is presumably supposed to assume independence, else the problem cannot be solved. In many cases, independence is unreasonable, since a power surge often fries more than one component. There should also have been an explicit time interval over which the probabilities $a$, $b$, and $c$ are taken. No device lives forever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is right if the three events are independent.

Answer (score 2):

Given the above-mentioned, crucial assumption, your solution looks good.

However, if that assumption does *not* hold, you would have to re-work your answer.

Comment: If the assumption of independence does not hold, then there's really not enough information.

Comment: @MichaelHardy unless the posted problem is not the complete version ;)